MacBook Air(2020) screen flickers and goes blank after being idle, but device stays on
I'm experiencing an issue with my MacBook Air. When I open the device after it's been idle for an extended period, the screen starts flickering and eventually goes blank. However, the device itself remains on — the keyboard backlight is still lit, and any audio (like music or videos) continues to play, indicating it's not in sleep mode.
I've noticed that this problem often resolves if I start using the laptop right away or plug it in, which increases the device temperature slightly.
Does anyone have any suggestions on how I might prevent this issue, or insights into what could be causing it?
Thanks in advance for any help!


Those lines at the bottom of your screen indicate physical or electrical damage of some sort to the Mac's hardware which drives the screen, or the screen itself. There is little chance it is software related.

Thanks for the input,but the lines are not there all the time only when the display is about to turn off this is how it starts from the bottom

It is still a symptom of HW failure (or imminent HW failure.) I've never seen a laptop screen with problems like this that just gets better, or is the cause of software problems. Most times they eventually fail without warning. If you have the wherewithal to have it checked out by a competent Apple service facility, do so as soon as possible.

Thank you will get it checked and post an update soon on this
